# Prove that for any fixed $n>1$ there exists an infinite amount of such prime $p$, that $p\equiv 1 (n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Prove that for any fixed $n>1$ there exists an infinite amount of such prime $p$, that $p\equiv 1 (n)$

Essintially, what's in the title, how do I that?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $p≡1(n)$ ?

Comment: I mean $p\equiv 1 (mod\ n)$

Comment: @orca This is a standard notation for [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation). *mod* is sometimes omitted.

Comment: Use Cyclotomic Polynomials. See e.g. [here](https://www.google.lt/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec12.pdf&ved=0CCcQFjACahUKEwijzY6UhbDIAhUCSBQKHTsDBEw&usg=AFQjCNFfJPeeKoFqIDVDMubFkgjggBkB1g&sig2=8hBdAtfFfWP28JqMVsXbVA).

Comment: See [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)